# Weird String won't split (Whitespaces or Tabs)

Tags: java

I am having troubles splitting this string into the different values.

When splitting it using `R`, there is no problem splitting it using sep="\t".

But in Java I cannot make it work.
I copied the string from the file that I am reading from and it seems to be reproducible in the online java fiddlers.

I've already tried "\s+", "\t+", "\t", "\t", "\t+".

Maybe the String is not tab delimited? But why does `R` work then?

```
public class JavaFiddle {

  static String s = "   1   0   3        150.00";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(s.split("\\t+")[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `s.split("\t+")`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well, it doesnt make a difference, when I tried it. But as far as I've read, I need to escape the \t , so it becomes \\t

Comment: You don't need to escape, using `\t` works fine. Otherwise, please print out the result of `System.out.println((int) s.charAt(0))`.

Comment: If you're splitting it on tab in R, and not in Java, then you're not trying to split the same string. (Perhaps your IDE has different settings for what to do when you save a file with *literal* tabs in it between the two.) If the above is a copy-and-paste from your IDE (which it should be when asking this kind of question), that's the problem: The string contains no tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `\\s` :

```
public class JavaFiddle {

  static String s = "   1   0   3        150.00";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] split = s.trim().split("\\s+");
      for(int i=0; i < split.length; i++){
      System.out.println(i + "-->" + split[i]);    
      }     
  }
}
```

And the output is:

```
0-->1
1-->0
2-->3
3-->150.00
```

Comment: @HideAndSeek Yeah, because while pasting the string into an editor, one cannot be sure that tab delimiters will be treated as tab delimiter. It varies because of different encoding schemes being used. The provided string doesn't contain any tab delimiter. You may check it by `s.contains("\t")`, it will result into false. That's why your provided string is not being split. Better to use @riorio way. `s.split("\\s+")` as it splits a string on the basis of white spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! 
In my code I am using "\\s+" to read directly from the file and it also works. Maybe the internal implementation of the split method in R or Java handles this.